# I can not authorize to hitbtc api from c#

Tags: c#, authorization, exchange-server, trading

my code is:

```
HitBtcApi.HitBtcApi hitbtc = new HitBtcApi.HitBtcApi();
hitbtc.Authorize("xxx", "xxx");            
RestRequest request2 = new RestRequest("/api/2/account/balance", method.GET);
var x= await hitbtc.Execute(request2, true);    
MessageBox.Show(x.content.ToString());
```

this error rising when running:
{"error":{"code":1001,"message":"Authorization required","description":""}} but when i use "/api/2/public/symbol" instead of "/api/2/account/balance" it work. please help me. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Did you activate the access right to the specific API for your API key?

https://hitbtc.com/settings/api-keys

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new
                    System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                        Convert.ToBase64String(
                            Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                                "user:pass")));

                var result = await (await client.GetAsync("https://api.hitbtc.com/api/2/trading/balance")).Content
                    .ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
```

Comment: thanks for your help. my access don't had problem. when i try your code it worked like a charm.

Comment: No problem, Mark it as answer if it is so!

Comment: Hi dear Khatibzadeh, can you please show to me how can i make  a buy and sell order and how can cancel an order. thanks